# centering google maps only with kml

Tags: google-maps, kml

I have a web page that receives some parameters and produces a KML file with many placemarks in it.

Is there a KML element that forces the map to open centered and/or zoomed on a point I choose?

Thanks,
Ami

Comment: Consider [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answers to some more of [your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1197110+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1) to encourage users to answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a [`<LookAt>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#lookat) element to your [`<Document>`](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#document).

Comment: hmmm... it seems the user has to double click in order to activate this.
I need something that doesn't require user interaction.
The map has to center automatically on a point when it opens.

But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Incorrect. The <LookAt> on the <Document> will be used when the file is first opened (in GE at least anyway!). Try it.

Comment: Assuming @AmiMalimovka tried this out in GE as well, it might be that this depends on the version of GE and/or on the way the document was opened (double click vs. open file dialog, GE already running vs. not running). OS might play a role as well.